# How to do BDD using CQRS?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, bdd, cqrs

I test my apps using BDD - approach. So far it was simple, because I had one facade and one repository per module. Unit tests of my module (facade) looked like:

In test:

```
       private TaskForm createSimpleTask() {
          return new TaskForm("Task1", "Text1");
       }


    // given

        TaskForm form = createSimpleTask();

    // when

        TaskDto savedTask = taskFacade.save(form);

    // then

        TaskWithUserDto loadedTask = taskFacade.load(savedTask.getId());
        assertNonNull(loadedTask);
        assertEquals(loadedTask.getTitle(), "Task1");
        assertEquals(loadedTask.getText(), "Text1");
        assertEquas(loadedTask.getAuthor(), "Michal");
```

In taskFacade:

```
   TaskDto save(TaskForm form) {
        UserDto currentUser = userFacade.getLoggedUser();
        Task task = taskFactory.create(form, currentUser.getId());
        return taskRepo.save(task).dto();
    }

    TaskWithUserDto load(long taskId) {
        Task task = taskRepo.findById(taskId);
        UserDto user = userFacade.load(task.getUserId());
        return new TaskWithUserDto(task.getTitle(), task.getText(), user.getName());
    }
```

I've started using CQRS now and I don't know how to test system with this architecture. Why ?

Instead of one facade I have CommandTaskFacade and QueryTaskRepository. The first one returns only long or void (it has only commands) and the second one has a lot of query methods which return a read models (dtos for UI).

Therefore I have TaskRepo with Task entity - business object without getters and mapping methods to dto (as previously) and QueryTaskRepository with simple searching methods returning dtos.

In integration tests it works fine, because I use real DB, but in unit tests I inject a simple in memory repositories implementations which use HashMap. Without CQRS it's easy to test, because I have one model and data source (one repo with one hash map), but now InMemoryQueryTaskRepository knows nothing about state in InMemoryTaskRepository.

Do you have any ideas how to test it (unit) ?

Answer (score 1):

> I've started using CQRS now and I don't know how to test it. Why ?

It sounds like you are missing a piece.

> In integration tests it works fine, because I use real DB, but in unit tests I inject a simple in memory repositories implementations which use HashMap. Without CQRS it's easy to test, because I have one model and data source (one repo with one hash map), but now InMemoryQueryTaskRepository knows nothing about state in InMemoryTaskRepository.

So you need to be thinking about one of two patterns, depending on which is closer to your actual intended design.

1) If you are expecting there to be a single "database" that all of your repositories talk to, then in your tests your repositories should be talking to the *same* in memory database (aka, the same hash map).

2) If you are expecting there to be two (or more) "databases", with the "read" repository talking to one database and the "write" repository to another, then there is going to be some process that copies/projects information from the write database to the read database, and that projection needs to be expressed in your "unit test".

From the way you describe your integration test, I suspect the first case is the closer fit.

> how can I map Task from HashMaps of Tasks to any read model if Task doesn't have getters and toDto methods ? In real db I can just select/join data but in Java ?

How do you get the data out of `Task` to store it in the DB?  Use that.

> Therefore according to your suggestion Task (as domain object) should have toDbRow() method which produces dto representing DB row yes

The spelling `toDbRow` implies that you are coupling the interface to a specific database representation.  Closer would be storage agnostic Value that describes the current state.

As for the API, it might be a zero argument query, or it might accept a function that takes some values are arguments and returns something useful.

```
<T> T currentState( MagicTaskStateHelper<T> helper )
```

Comment: Yes, I want to use the first one, but how can I map Task from HashMaps of Tasks to any read model if Task doesn't have getters and toDto methods ? 

In real db I can just select/join data but in Java ? Maybe reflection :D

Comment: So far I have used Spring Data + JPA so .. I know, business object isn't jpa entity. It works because JPA uses reflection. 


Therefore according to your suggestion Task (as domain object) should have toDbRow() method which produces dto representing DB row yes ? :) It sounds reasonably.

Comment: you should raise domainEvents from your aggregates and update inmemory projections

Comment: I have one DB - common for write and read so I dont need to emit events and update.

Comment: I can't imagine this. Could you in your free time describe an example where You have a Task and want to save it to DB ? How can I know about state of Task if this class doesn't have getters and toDto() methods ?